# some french charecter is not able to fetch in mchart

Tags: amcharts

I have problem in character encoding. I am using amchart to create and populate chart in UI. But in one page due to character encoding graph is not coming correctly. When we replace normal English character to french character (é or à ) graph is not coming. Please refer codes to understand my problem.

```
"title" : "Pin déjà utilisé",
"type" : "column",
"color" : "#000000",
"valueField" : "Pin déjà utilisé"

json.addProperty("Date", resultSet.getString("Date"));
                json.addProperty("Authentique", resultSet.getInt("noOfPinGenuine"));
                json.addProperty("Pin déjà utilisé", resultSet.getInt("noOfPinUsed"));
```

Please advise how to resolve this problem I have to use french character in valueField because I have to export this graph in CSV format and column name should be in French.

Comment: Are you escaping the fields with UTF-8 characters correctly? Post a fiddle that reproduces your problem. [It works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/5zLp1pwn/)

Comment: when I write like as I attached in question then graph for valueField Pin déjà utilisé is not coming, and when I use "Pin deja utilise" in place of that then graph is coming correctly. Also Encoding type is UTF-8

Comment: I understand that, however, as you can see in the fiddle I linked in my last response, it works for me, so there's something wrong with your setup. Can you reproduce the problem in jsfiddle? Are the properties in your JSON escaped correctly? You need to provide more information.